# Can I connect to Google Cloud SQL with horizontal scale from Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, scale, horizontal-scaling

I need to make my database to scale horizontally (creating new machines). It should be connect to an instance from Google Compute Engine that should be to scale as well. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You may Horizontally scale a Google Cloud SQL database. It has to be done with [ProxySQL](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/horizontally-scale-mysql-database-backend-with-google-cloud-sql-and-proxysql).

If you would like to run a GCE instance as a frontend and make it scale horizontally, you may use a [Managed Instance Group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/).